# Replace backslash(\) with empty string

Tags: c#, backslash

Hi all I am having a problem while replacing string which have backslash()

```
string sRegex = "2004\01".Replace("\\", "");
Response.Write(sRegex); // which is giving me 20041
```

But the same when I include two backslashes giving me the output as expected

```
string sRegex = "2004\\01".Replace("\\", "");
Response.Write(sRegex); // which is giving me 200401

string sReplace = "2004\01";
string sRegex = sReplace.Replace("\\", "");
```

So is there any possibility to over come the first case? so that it should display the same result

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\0` is null character you need to use verbatim string so the compiler will treat your first back-slash as is instead of escape sequence

```
string sRegex = @"2004\01".Replace("\\", "");
```

Comment: I would also suggest `"2004\\01"` in addition, as Dotnet isn't aware of escape sequences.

Comment: Hi when I am directly assigning the value it is working fine if I assign the same value to some other string and then need to compare will this work. Look at my update

Comment: @Dotnet Yes just add a @ beginning of your string literal or use two backslash (per one slash) to escape your characters as Joe suggested

Comment: @Dotnet also you might wanna look at the documentation: [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)